# How can I take the current integer value out of my array loop when I press my button on Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, ibaction

I need to take the current value of mtype and pass it forward to Mselect so that the image pushed forward is the same as the one rotating in the animation.

here is the code sample

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    //Array to hold  Images
    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:Mush_Count];

    for (mtype = 1; mtype < Mush_Count; mtype++)
    {
        [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mush%i.png", mtype]]];
        //make button

        SelectBt.imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];
        SelectBt.imageView.animationDuration = 5;
        [SelectBt.imageView startAnimating];

        Mselect = mtype;

    }
}    
-(IBAction)Selection:(id)sender{
    [self Placement];
}

-(void)Placement{
    if (Place1Occ == NO) {
        [self Place1];
    }
}
-(void)Place1{
    if (Place1Occ == NO) {
        Place1.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mush%i.png", Mselect]];
    Place1Occ = YES;
    }
}
```

The animation loops just fine and the selection of the images works but it's not selecting the image the is currently on the screen it selects the last image on the Array.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is mtype a local variable? What about Mselect?

Comment: They are both int and both are local I really just need the value of mtype when I click. as its rotating through the images mtype is = 1-9 I need that digit to assign the proper value to my UIImage views.

Comment: For some reason it gives the last value of the array which ends up assigning the last image in the array. No matter when I press the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (mtype = 1; mtype < Mush_Count; mtype++)
{
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mush%i.png", mtype]]];
}
```

That loop is enough to build the array of images - you don't need to set the imageView's animation images until this loop completes and the array is populated.
As it stands, you reset the animation images each loop and set `Mselect` to `type` each iteration: this is why you always get the last image index stored in `Mselect`

This code should be after the for loop:

```
    SelectBt.imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];
    SelectBt.imageView.animationDuration = 5;
    [SelectBt.imageView startAnimating];
```

As far as I know, you can't get the current frame of the animation directly - you have to create a timer when you start the animation and have this count the number of frames (by increasing your `Mselect` value. Then use that to load the current image

Comment: That was my original plan but I was worried that a timer separate from the loop would cause it to give me a different image then the one currently flipping through the button.

Comment: I created timer but I'm coding my if statements wrong how would you count the number of frames on the button so that it corresponds to the  Mselect value. I can't place Uibutton value inside the if statement

Comment: int numFrames = [imageArray count];

in your timer:  Mselect++; if (Mselect > (numFrames - 1)) Mselect = 0;

Comment: Thanks Dav, it dind't work I'll try again later in the mronign I've been up all night stuck on this. My next question to you was going to be why not just skip the timer and assign the the value of image arraycount to Mselect but that didn't work either. With this setup it keeps assigning the first image in the array. I've double checked the code over and over to see if  I missed something that is causing this but I can't find it.

Comment: got the timer to work now i just need to match the rate of the frames.

Comment: This is what I meant, this is why i was avoiding the timer because it's almost impossible to match the duration and the timer so that they are always corresponding to the same int value.

Comment: Maybe set the image in the image view using a timer rather than using the imageView startAnimating?  It looks like you are making a custom component so if you set the image in the timer you always know which one to use?

Comment: thanks that works perfectly. One last thing everytime i press the button it shows the image of the image but it selects the image you clicked on. then it coninues through the loop.

Comment: Are you using UIButton setImage: forState: UIControlStateNormal? You have to make sure the image is set for the up and down states

Comment: no I wasn't I'll set it up now i was just using this           mtype++;
    if (mtype > Mush_Count) {
        mtype = 1;
    }
    Mselect = mtype;
    
    selectBt.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mush%i.png", mtype]];

Comment: No worries - feel free to mark the answer as correct to prevent other people trying to fix it even though it is now solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is SelectBT a subclass of UIButton? if so is it the (id)sender coming from your IBAction?

If so then you can just grab the image directly from the SelectBT instance by calling `sender.imageView.image`

As an aside, objective-C convention is to capitalize ClassNames, but start instances with lowerCase like this `ClassName *instanceOfClassName` and you're likely to take flack for it around here if you don't adhere to that convention

***Update***

Could you bump your imageArray into a class variable or a property? It already contains all the fully loaded UIImages, which you can get back out by calling `[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]`

Then you just have to keep track of which numeric index is facing your user, or which index they tapped and pull the corresponding image.

Feel free to post your whole class if you'd like us to explain more.

Comment: Thanks for tip. SelectBT is a UIbutton

Comment: Awesome, you'll have to cast sender to SelectBT too.  `UIImage *targetImage = (SelectBT*)sender.imageview.image;`

Comment: When I changed it to the code above it just gave me the first image in the array.

Comment: I changed the  code on -(void)Place1{ Place1.image = selectBt.imageview.image; }

Comment: Ok, that sounds better because i am going to need the index number for my subsequent coding. If you don't mind please explain more I am still learning. You said to post my Whole class? I am trying to work the code a piece at a time so i don't get lost so right now I just trying to make my first 7 images work as per my selection.

Comment: Ryan could you give me an example